# Java Runtime Error - Must have access to system preferences

Tags: java, compilation, system, preferences

I've recently started a java project for uni and wanted to incorporate a library, not sure if I can add links but the library is a date/time thing. I have incorporated the library successfully but I now get the error:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: You must have access to the system preferences in order to run the evaluation version of the Dated Collections Library.

I have searched everywhere for at least a solid 25 minutes and cannot find an answer to this issue. I am sure it is something very simple?

Thank you in advance.

Edit:

The read me states:
"The library must have access to the system's preferences in order to run", however does not state how?

Edit 2: Resolved by running intellij as admin, thank you.

Comment: Maybe the library has the ability to modify the system's date/time, in which case it needs special permissions? That would not really be a code problem; if that's it the library would probably work if you ran as an administrative user. Note that I DO NOT suggest this in general. IF this is the reason for the error, and if you are not trying to modify the system's date/time, then I would consider this a flaw of the library. I might be tempted to abandon the library if it's not from a trustworthy enough source.

Comment: just a thought - have you tried running as Administrator ? may be it is an access right issue...

Comment: @Aaron I agree that it is not a code problem but rather a configuration problem and unfortunately this library has been used in code that have been used in a repo and my job is to amend it. I also agree it may not be the best choice however I'd like to stick through it for at least for now and would just like to understand how to resolve this :(

Comment: @Plirkee wow that worked, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the community; glad you got a useful answer. Since this is not a programming question, and since it looks like you have your answer anyway (and that without any answers posted), I've flagged for closing the question. @ToastAndJam an FYI for the future: this question would have been good for StackExchange's SuperUser sub-site rather than StackExchange's StackOverflow.

Comment: Another comment, albeit fairly moot: Your comments seem to betray your question. That is, your question states that you "want to incorporate" a library, which was what prompted my initial response. Your later comments, however, suggested that this is an existing project already using the library. Note that answers you receive will be biased by the provided information. I agree with you that abandoning a library in an existing project is not trivial.